# Python input invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, string, input, literals

My python code is working perfectly fine. But the problem is with the website where it wants the input to be in string format with spaces in between and be accepted as an integer

Below is my actual python code

```
    x = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    
    prod = 1
    
    if(x >= 0 and x <= 9 and n >=0 and n <= 9):
        for i in range(n):
            prod = prod * x
    print(prod)
```

This code actually calculates the power of a number.
Ex: `x = 3, n = 4, prod = 81`

Now the error is that

```
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 3 4'

    x = int(input())
    n = int(input())
```

I have to take two inputs `x & n` in this format `3 4`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `x, y = map(int, input().split())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
x = int(input())
n = int(input())
```

with

```
s = input('enter two integers: ')
x, n = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid because your string has spaces. Just `split` on space to get a list of two numbers, and perhaps validate the length of the resulting list as well, depending on what you might get as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are using int(). Hence, it requires an integer value within quotes from input(). Space doesn't come under a category called integers. To resolve this error, use split()

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the code**

```
x=int(input("Enter number1:"))
n=int(input("Enter number2:"))
prod = 1
if(x >= 0 and x <= 9 and n >=0 and n <= 9):
    for i in range(n):
        prod = prod * x
print(prod)
```

Hope it is helpful